# How to get data from json format using groovy?

Tags: groovy

i have a request in soapui which returns a json response.
i'm using groovy to retrieve the content of the response.
response :

```
<item><response>{
  "timestamp": "2016-04-01T16:40:34",
  "data": [
    {
      "deleted_at": null,
      "userid": "b6d66002-8da4-4c03-928c-46871f084fb8",
      "updated_by": null,
      "created_at": "2016-03-01T16:40:34",
      "updated_at": "2016-03-01T16:40:34",
      "created_by": null,
      "value": "hBeO",
      "setting": "test",
      "name": "test2"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}</response></item>
```

From this response i want to retrieve each node like: 
deleted_at
created_at

so i use this groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = context.expand( '${set_settings#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://wato.io/ns/20160131\'; //ns1:set_settings_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response)

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("user_id", result.data.userid)
```

and i receive this error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestCasePro.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) values: [userid, [b6df6662-8da4-4c03-928c-46871f084fb8]] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String) error at line: 8
```

It works only for timestamp node.
any help please.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `result.data` is a list, so it returns a list (containing one item) for `userid`

You need to just get the first item from the list, so try:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("user_id", result.data.userid.head())
```

Comment: now there is no error message but the result is null, it stores nothing in property.